# Online WCF RestFull services url

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, wcf-data-services

I want to use WCF with RESTful in my application.

But i want test that before with any available online service.

Is there any online deployed `WCF RESTful` service available?

if available please provide link.

Thanks 
Madhu

Comment: _Is there any online deployed WCF RESTful service available?_ Loads but I'm guessing none that you can test your code with

Comment: @dkozl Why cant i use them?

Comment: I just don't understand why you would want to use some random RESTful service, with different set of calls to test if your application works

Comment: @dkozl I just want to know how it works. I will modify my app to work with that web service. if you have any please provide the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try these URLs: http://services.odata.org/v4/OData/OData.svc/ or [http://services.odata.org/v4/(S(readwrite))/OData/OData.svc/](http://services.odata.org/v4/%28S%28readwrite%29%29/OData/OData.svc/) or
http://services.odata.org/v4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/

Comment: Are they using RESTful?

Comment: Yes, they are Restful odata service. But now it is recommended to use WebApi to build these services. Here are some examples, for your reference:https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/